# JavaScript files in browser console are loaded with ?_=id

Tags: javascript, angular, browser

Why the javaScript files in the browser console are loaded with the ?_=id

1. Is this the current session id where the JavaScript is loaded ??
2. Is there any performance gain with this ??

See the below image

[image]

Comment: force to capture file withourt caching, this tcnique is used when your calling a ajax with no cache

Comment: It's because so that the browser won't cache the files.

Answer (score 0):

It’s important to make resources (images, scripts, stylesheets, etc.) cacheable so your pages load faster when users come back. A recent study from Website Optimization shows that the top 1000 home pages average over 50 resources per page! Being able to skip 50 HTTP requests and just read those resources from the browser’s cache dramatically speeds up pages.

***This is versioning whenever you are releasing your application it generate random version to override previous cache version of scripts.***

Comment: You should provide a link for those "studies"